# rpmbuild: brp-java-repack-jars changes jar permissions

Tags: linux, jar, file-permissions, rpm, rpmbuild

Consider a SPEC file containing:

```
%install
install -m u=rwx,g=rx,o= -D bin/blah.jar ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_libexecdir}/foo/blah.jar
```

Then in the `%files` section, the permissions are not changed (say, `%defattr(-,bubba,users,-)`).

Installing the RPM results in `blah.jar` having permissions `644` instead of `640`. Indeed, no matter what permissions are used in the `install` command, they're reset to the default `640`. I've found that the cause is the jar repacking, as permissions are maintained if I disable repacking by adding `%define __jar_repack %{nil}` to the SPEC file.

This is a nasty bug of the repacker.

How do I get both repacking to work *and* the permissions to be preserved (and I mean preserved, not setting them instead in the `%files` section, as then I'd have to mention individual files not only in `%install` but in `%files` as well, rather than just whole directories in the latter)?

Comment: What OS is this? What is the repacker doing? Can you edit the repacker?

Comment: CentOS 7. This repack runs by default on several other distros, and at least on RedHat and Fedora. The description I've found is here: https://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-devel-java-list/2008-September/msg00040.html However, I notice even when what is explained there doesn't apply to my use case, it still reduces the size of the jars by quite a lot, which is a good reason to continue to be able to use it.

Comment: How are you creating your jars? Ultimately the command that it uses to put the jars back together (assuming the `brp-java-repack-jars` script I'm looking at isn't too out of date) is `/usr/bin/zip -q -X -9 $j -@` so the size difference you are seeing might just be the compression they are using (and dropping extra attributes and directory names). You could see if doing that yourself gets you comparable results.

Comment: I'm creating the jars using "maven package", and the project files are configured so that dependencies are left as external, and not embedded in the jar files.